# golang json marshal: how to omit empty nested struct

Tags: json, go

[go playground](https://play.golang.org/p/sA0D6pHZnc)

As shown in the code above, one can use `json:",omitempty"` to omit certain fields in a struct to appear in json.

For example

```
type ColorGroup struct {
    ID     int `json:",omitempty"`
    Name   string
    Colors []string
}
type Total struct {
    A ColorGroup`json:",omitempty"`
    B string`json:",omitempty"`
}
group := Total{
       A: ColorGroup{},

}
```

In this case, `B` won't show up in `json.Marshal(group)`

However, if

```
group := Total{
       B:"abc",

}
```

`A` still shows up in `json.Marshal(group)`

```
{"A":{"Name":"","Colors":null},"B":"abc"}
```

Question is how do we get only

```
{"B":"abc"}
```

EDIT:
After some googling, here is a suggestion [use pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18088294/how-to-not-marshal-an-empty-struct-into-json-with-go), in other words, turn `Total` into

```
type Total struct {
    A *ColorGroup`json:",omitempty"`
    B string`json:",omitempty"`
}
```

Comment: In case this isn't working for some people, the comma before omitempty in the struct tag is important. When I left it out, the field was always omitted, even if it was not-nill.

Comment: Just in case anybody run into my issue... Don't place a space between the comma and omitempty.

Comment: Maybe this answer could help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/18088527/2271198

Comment: There is a proposal to fix this behavior: https://github.com/golang/go/issues/11939 ; alternately there is a proposal for a "v2" JSON encoder which would include fixes for this behavior: https://github.com/golang/go/discussions/63397

Answer (score 67):

From [the documentation](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Marshal):

> Struct values encode as JSON objects. Each exported struct field becomes a member of the object unless
>
> - the field's tag is "-", or
> - the field is empty and its tag specifies the "omitempty" option.
>
> The empty values are false, 0, any **nil pointer** or interface value, and any array, slice, map, or string of length zero.

In your declaration of `group`, it's implicit that `group.A` will be the zero value of the `ColorGroup` struct type.  And notice that zero-values-of-struct-types is not mentioned in that list of things that are considered "empty values".

As you found, the workaround for your case is to use a pointer.  This will work if you don't specify `A` in your declaration of `group`.  If you specify it to be a pointer to a zero-struct, then it will show up again.

[playground link](https://play.golang.org/p/R_JfT9G4J4):

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    type colorGroup struct {
        ID     int `json:",omitempty"`
        Name   string
        Colors []string
    }
    type total struct {
        A *colorGroup `json:",omitempty"`
        B string     `json:",omitempty"`
    }

    groupWithNilA := total{
        B: "abc",
    }
    b, err := json.Marshal(groupWithNilA)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("error:", err)
    }
    os.Stderr.Write(b)

    println()

    groupWithPointerToZeroA := total{
        A: &colorGroup{},
        B: "abc",
    }
    b, err = json.Marshal(groupWithPointerToZeroA)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("error:", err)
    }
    os.Stderr.Write(b)
}
```

Comment: I know this is an old post. But I have a question. If using a pointer is a workaround, what's the catch?

Comment: Why not always use pointers for field types that are structs?

Comment: I know these are old comments, but "the catch" and "why not always use pointers" is because we then always have to check if the pointer is `nil`, otherwise we could panic the process by doing the nil pointer dereference when accessing nil struct field. `if g.A.Name != "" {}; if g.A.ID == 0 {}` would turn into `if g.A != nil { if g.A.Name != "" { } // Colors and ID check...}`.

Answer (score 2):

This is an alternative solution, in case you would like to avoid using pointers to structs. The `Container` struct implements `json.Marshaller`, which allows us to decide which members of the strcut should be omitted.

https://play.golang.com/p/hMJbQ-QQ5PU

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    for _, c := range []Container{
        {},
        {
            Element: KeyValue{
                Key:   "foo",
                Value: "bar",
            },
        },
    } {
        b, err := json.Marshal(c)
        if err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }
        fmt.Println(string(b))
    }
}

type Container struct {
    Element KeyValue
}

func (c Container) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error) {
    // Alias is an alias type of Container to avoid recursion.
    type Alias Container

    // AliasWithInterface wraps Alias and overrides the struct members,
    // which we want to omit if they are the zero value of the type.
    type AliasWithInterface struct {
        Alias
        Element interface{} `json:",omitempty"`
    }

    return json.Marshal(AliasWithInterface{
        Alias:   Alias(c),
        Element: c.Element.jsonValue(),
    })
}

type KeyValue struct {
    Key   string
    Value string
}

// jsonValue returns nil if kv is the zero value of KeyValue. It returns kv otherwise.
func (kv KeyValue) jsonValue() interface{} {
    var zero KeyValue
    if kv == zero {
        return nil
    }
    return kv
}
```

EDIT: added documentation

Answer (score -21):

Easy way

```
type <name> struct {
< varname > < vartype > \`json : -\`
}
```

**Example :**

```
type Boy struct {
name string \`json : -\`
}
```

this way on marshaling `name` will not get serialized.

Comment: at least 15 people downvoted this without explaining to us why

Comment: @JeshanBabooa, 1. `name` field not exported! First letter of exported fields must be capital. 2. `json:"-"` is effective when the field is exported. 3. and final word: if the field is exported `json:"-"` will omit it at all....