# Remove elements with empty value when no values

Tags: go, struct

I want to remove elements with empty value in struct. My script is below. Output of this script is `{"keyA":{}}`. I used `omitempty` to KeyA and KeyB. But an element with empty value is left. On the other hand KeyB is not shown. I want to show KeyA when it has values. I don't want to show KeyA when it has no values. Is there way to do this?

#### Script

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)

type sample struct {
    KeyA struct {
        Key1 string `json:"keyA1,omitempty"`
        Key2 string `json:"keyA2,omitempty"`
    } `json:"keyA,omitempty"`
    KeyB string `json:"keyB,omitempty"`
}

func main() {
    var s sample
    response, _ := json.Marshal(s)
    fmt.Println(string(response)) // {"keyA":{}}
}
```

Thank you so much for your time. And I'm sorry for my immature question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [golang json marshal: how to omit empty nested struct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33447334/golang-json-marshal-how-to-omit-empty-nested-struct)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try [this](https://play.golang.org/p/3zjm6j-MjAc):

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)
type KeyA struct {
    Key1 string `json:"keyA1,omitempty"`
    Key2 string `json:"keyA2,omitempty"`
} 
type sample struct {
    KeyA *KeyA  `json:"keyA,omitempty"`
    KeyB string `json:"keyB,omitempty"`
}

func main() {
    var s sample
    response, _ := json.Marshal(s)
    fmt.Println(string(response)) // {}
}
```

output:

```
{}
```

Comment: Thank you for your advices. How do I input values to "KeyA.Key1" and "KeyA.Key2" for this script?

Comment: Try [The Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/b5xM6dFsGVS), and [this](https://play.golang.org/p/uIOq5x1gRvd).  I hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you so much. I could understand.