# Parse structs from API

Tags: json, go

I am trying to access some information stored in a json file via Go. I have two related issues. One is that I'm not sure how to organize my structs and secondly how do I access them via a variable. I'll notate my code to make a little more sense

```
// To be clear, this is dummy info and I'm linting my actual json
// data. It loads fine, I just don't want to get hung up on this side
{
 "A": {
        "lob": "A",
        "url": [
                 "example.com",
                 "test.com"]
}
 "B": {
        "lob": "B",
        "url": [
                 "example2.com",
                 "test2.com"]

}
}
```

So the concern is that the structure of the options is identical. I am building this as part of a REST AP. The hope is that users can use http://testapi.com/getdata/A  and it will return the urls and name info under A and likewise for B. As is, it loads both of them as separate components of the same struct:

```
type SiteList struct {
    A struct {
        Lob string   `json:"lob"`
        URL []string `json:"url"`
    } `json:"test"`
    B struct {
        Lob string   `json:"lob"`
        URL []string `json:"url"`
    } `json:"test2"`
}
```

I can do .A or .B by hand but I'm wondering how to handle it when the requests come in so that my API will only return the data under A or B.

Comment: Use a map if fields names are not known at compile time or to access fields dynamically. E.g. `type SiteList map[string]Site`. (Consider not calling it list though; that's just misleading).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're going to consume the API via  accessing the API via http://testapi.com/getdata/A or http://testapi.com/getdata/B then `A` and `B` can be considered the parameters that drive the behavior of your API.

If you're passing `A`, you basically want to access the site data associated with `A` and if you're passing `B`, the site data for `B` should be returned.

An easy way to organize this data internally is to use a dedicated Go type `site` which holds `Lob` and `URL` and arrange everything in a map via `map[string]site`, which is initialized on startup of your server.

You can then dynamically access the parameter given to your API (`A` or `B`, but can be easily extended), lookup the site information from the map and, in case it's a valid site, return the corresponding data encoded as JSON.

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net/http"
)

type site struct {
    Lob string   `json:"lob"`
    URL []string `json:"url"`
}

var sites = map[string]site{
    "A": site{
        Lob: "A",
        URL: []string{
            "example.com",
            "test.com",
        },
    },
    "B": site{
        Lob: "B",
        URL: []string{
            "example2.com",
            "test2.com",
        },
    },
}

const endpoint = "/getdata/"

func handler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    lob := r.URL.Path[len(endpoint):]
    s, ok := sites[lob]
    if !ok {
        w.WriteHeader(http.StatusNotFound)
        return
    }

    resp, err := json.Marshal(s)
    if err != nil {
        w.WriteHeader(http.StatusInternalServerError)
        return
    }

    w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8")
    w.Write(resp)
}

func main() {
    http.HandleFunc(endpoint, handler)
    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil))
}
```

Comment: You rule. I can't look at it until after work but I suspect this is exactly what I needed

Comment: @SteveB Any success with the proposed approach?

Comment: The answer ended up being a mashup of this and a solution I modified from somewhere else. Part of my solution was making my json a []structs that I could iterate through. Not long after, I figured out gorilla's schema which made passing values really simple. That you to everyone who helped. I am marking this answer as solved because it absolutely worked as expected.  My json structure was separate

Answer (score 0):

Missing values in the json will be unmarshalled with their zero values. An `int` will be `0`, a `string` will be `""`, a `map` and any pointer will be `nil`. Structs will be initialized, but their fields will have the zero value.

In your case, when comcast is missing in the json, B will be initialized as a struct, where `Lob` is `""` and `URL` is an empty slice of string.

Comment: While this is good info and I will certainly pocket it for another time, my current concern is not missing values, I know that url will always be a []string, for example.

I am looking of how to use a varialbe as a struct parameter.
Imagine I have bigstruct which is a struct of type Sitelist that has two structs (A and B) in it, as above. I have a variable that  val := "A" and I want to use that variable to pull just the info for A. I essentially want bigstruct.A  but I need to deliver A or B depending on the value of that variable

Comment: In this case I think that your question was a bit unclear. What exactly do you want to know?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you have a struct `SiteList` and depending on if they user navigates to `/getData/A` or `/getData/B` you want to serve  `SiteList.A` or `SiteList.B`.

From the json marshal [docs here](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Marshal) or this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33447334/golang-json-marshal-how-to-omit-empty-nested-struct) you can leave out some fields of a struct when they are empty. Basically if there's no data in that field then it will not appear in the marshalled json.

> The "omitempty" option specifies that the field should be omitted from
>   the encoding if the field has an empty value, defined as false, 0, a
>   nil pointer, a nil interface value, and any empty array, slice, map,
>   or string.

With that in mind, if you have the control in the handlers of the requests to be able to set the values in `SiteList` according to the path then you could make use of this feature.

If you extract the shared parts of `A` and `B` into a struct:

```
type Inner struct {
    Lob string `json:"lob"`
    URL []string `json:"url"`
}

// using pointers here for A and B means setting to nil is empty
type SiteList struct {
    A *Inner `json:"test,omitempty"`
    B *Inner `json:"test2,omitempty"`
}
```

And then set the one that you do not want to be in the response body to nil. (nil is empty for a pointer, so it will not get marshalled.)