# Go lang json.Marshall() ignores omitempty in ByteArray Fields

Tags: json, go

Please see below.

https://play.golang.org/p/HXrqLqYIgz

My expected value is:

```
{"Byte2":0,"Name":"bob"}
```

But Actual:

```
{"ByteArray":[0,0,0,0],"Byte2":0,"Name":"bob"}
```

According to the document (https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/)

> The empty values are false, 0, any nil pointer or interface value, and any array, slice, map, or string of length zero.

Therefore, json.Marshall() ignores omitempty-tag, because [0 0 0 0] is not zero-length nor 0 nor nil.

And now, to get the expected value, What should we do?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18088294/how-to-not-marshal-an-empty-struct-into-json-with-go

Comment: It cannot omit an byte array: It's a value type and there always present with it's default value.

Answer (score 4):

A few options:

1. Make `A` an instance of a type with its own `MarshalJSON` method and implement the behavior you want there (e.g. not including `ByteArray` if all of its values are zero).
2. Change the type of `ByteArray`. `[]byte` would work since it defaults to an empty slice, and `*[4]byte` would work since it defaults to `nil`. Including a pointer is a common way of dealing with a field that's only sometimes present in serialization. Of course this does require a little more space, a little more indirection, and a little more GC work.

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to either make `ByteArray` a slice, or a pointer to array:

```
type A struct {
    ByteArray *[4]byte `json:",omitempty"`
    Byte1     byte     `json:",omitempty"`
    Byte2     byte
    Name      string `json:",omitempty"`
}
```

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/nYBqGrSA1L.

Comment: Lovely answer. Thanks for creating Playground.