# Omitting JSON for Empty Custom Type

Tags: go, marshalling

I am trying to write a custom marshaler for a possibly `nil` database type. It is structured in the exact same way as the `sql.NullFloat64` type:

```
type NullFloat64 sql.NullFloat64

func (ni *NullFloat64) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error) {
    if !ni.Valid {
        return []byte("null"), nil
    }
    return json.Marshal(ni.Float64)
}
```

Which is a part of larger `struct` to be marshaled:

```
type Data struct {
    X time.Time `json:"x"`
    Y float32 `json:"y"`
    Stderr NullFloat64 `json:"stderr"`
}
```

If I try to `json.Marshal()` this `struct`, it works correctly, creating:

```
{"x":"2017-01-12T23:36:12-05:00","y":4,"stderr":null}
```

I would like to omit the JSON key entirely if the value is `null`. I added `json:"stderr,omitempty"` to `Data`.

Per the suggestion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18089594/1944335), I tried just returning a `nil` value from `MarshalJSON`, but got:

```
json: error calling MarshalJSON for type common.NullFloat64: unexpected end of JSON input
```

I also tried updating `Data` as:

```
type Data struct {
    X time.Time `json:"x"`
    Y float32 `json:"y"`
    Stderr *NullFloat64 `json:"stderr,omitempty"`
}
```

And marshaling:

```
Data {
    X: datetime,
    Y: value,
    Stderr: &stderr,
}
```

But got the same error when returning `nil` from `MarshalJSON` as before.

So, how can I implement `MarshalJSON` for a custom type and omit the key when marshaling?
Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you create you type like so:

```
Data {
    X: datetime,
    Y: value,
    Stderr: nil,
}
```

`omitempty` will kick in and "do the right thing". Sadly, I'm pretty sure this won't help you.

If you really want to omit a field based and internal state, you need to implement `json.Marshaller` on your structure, not its children. The easiest way to do this would be as follows:

```
func (d Data) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error) {
    if !d.Stderr.Valid {
        return json.Marshal(Data{d.X, d.Y, nil})
    }
    return json.Marshal(d)
}
```

Comment: By marshaling the struct itself, I get `fatal error: stack overflow` error.