# Type conversion between two struct pointers

Tags: go, struct, type-conversion

I have a `struct` that consists of a custom `time.Time` defined for the sake of it having a custom `MarshalJSON()` interface, following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23696303/4935114)'s suggestion:

```
type MyTime time.Time
func (s myTime) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error) {
    t := time.Time(s)
    return []byte(t.Format(`"20060102T150405Z"`)), nil
}
```

I define a `MyStruct` type with `ThisDate` and `ThatDate` fields of type `*MyTime`:

```
type MyStruct struct {
    ThisDate *MyTime `json:"thisdate,omitempty"`
    ThatDate *MyTime `json:"thatdate,omitempty"`
}
```

As far as I understand, I need to use `*MyTime` and not `MyTime` so the `omitempty` tag will have an effect when I'll `MarshalJSON` a variable of this type, following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18088527/4935114)'s suggestion.

I use a library that has a function that returns me a `struct` with some fields of type `*time.Time`:

```
someVar := Lib.GetVar()
```

I tried to define a variable of type `MyStruct` like this:

```
myVar := &MyStruct{
    ThisDate: someVar.ThisDate
    ThatDate: someVar.ThatDate
}
```

Naturally, it gives me a compilation error:

```
cannot use someVar.ThisDate (variable of type *time.Time) as *MyTime value in struct literal ...
```

I tried typecasting `someVar.ThisDate` with `*`/`&` and without these without luck. I thought the following would work:

```
myVar := &MyStruct{
    ThisDate: *MyTime(*someVar.ThisDate)
    ThatDate: *MyTime(*someVar.ThatDate)
}
```

But it gives me a different compilation error:

```
invalid operation: cannot indirect MyTime(*someVar.ThisDate) (value of type MyTime) ...
```

It seems I probably lack basic understanding of pointers and dereferences in Go. Never the less, I would like to avoid finding a specific solution for my issue which comes down to the combination of the need to make `omitempty` have an effect and a custom `MarshalJSON`.

Comment: `(*MyTime)(someVar.ThisDate)` The `someVar.ThisDate` is already a `*time.Time` right? so you do not need the `*` in front of it. Additionally when converting to pointer types, ie `*T`, I would recommed to always put the pointer type in extra parentheses, ie `(*T)`. https://play.golang.com/p/jH9Q07sizID

Comment: That's very helpful, thank you! Could you perhaps explain further this syntax? I've seen it many times and I don't know even how to search for it in order to find documentation about it. Perhaps even a link to the proper place in http://tour.golang.org/ would do.

Comment: https://golang.org/ref/spec#Conversions *If the type starts with the operator * or <-, or if the type starts with the keyword func and has no result list, it must be parenthesized when necessary to avoid ambiguity*

Comment: If you understand the concept of operator precedence, or order-of-evaluation, you can see that `*T(v)` could be interpreted in two ways and is therefore ambiguous, so to *avoid the ambiguity* you can make your intent clear by adding parentheses `(*T)(v)`.

Comment: That's an excellent explanation @mkopriva - exactly what I was missing. Please feel free to put these words into an answer I'll mark as accepted.

Comment: Go doesn't have typecasting at all.

Comment: Please take time to also absorb what Flimzy said: in Go, there is no type_casting_ — that is, forced reinterpretation of a value of one type as that of another. Instead, Go has type _conversions;_ which differ in that they ever allow to convert values between compatible types where compatible roughly meaning "representing values which have the same memory layouts for their data".

Comment: Thanks @kostix, I edited the title of the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is the ambiguous syntax of `*T(v)` or whatever else you tried there. The [Golang's spec](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Conversions) gives useful examples for type conversions as this, quoting:

```
*Point(p)        // same as *(Point(p))
(*Point)(p)      // p is converted to *Point
```

Therefor, since `*Point` is needed, `*T(v)` should be used.

Comment: (*T)(v) for a *Point; to get a Point, it's then *(*T)(v).