# Omitempty field is not working, how to remove empty structs from the response body?

Tags: mysql, database, go, go-gorm, defaultifempty

[image: Api Response Image link]

```golang
type PolicySpec struct {
    Description      string       `json:"description" yaml:"description"`
    EndpointSelector Selector     `json:"endpointSelector,omitempty" yaml:"ingress,omitempty"`
    Severity         int          `json:"severity,omitempty" yaml:"severity,omitempty"`
    Tags             []string     `json:"tags,omitempty" yaml:"tags,omitempty"`
    Message          string       `json:"message,omitempty" yaml:"message,omitempty"`
    Process          KubeArmorSys `json:"process,omitempty" yaml:"process,omitempty"`
    File             KubeArmorSys `json:"file,omitempty" yaml:"network,omitempty"`
    Action           string       `json:"action,omitempty" yaml:"action,omitempty"`
}
```

I even though added omitempty in the fields yet getting the empty struct in the yaml and json, how to remove those empty structs from the api response body?

Comment: Change them to pointer types, and if `nil` they ought to be omitted. At least that's how it works with the encoding/json package, not sure about yaml. [`encoding/json`](https://pkg.go.dev/encoding/json#Marshal): *"The "omitempty" option specifies that the field should be omitted from the encoding if the field has an empty value, defined as **false, 0, a nil pointer, a nil interface value, and any empty array, slice, map, or string**."* -- You see? No mention of "empty struct" there.

Comment: got your point, thanks @mkopriva

Comment: @mkopriva I think as yaml library documentation says, Zero structs are omitted.

Comment: Hi @mkopriva for json would it also be the same, since i'm getting this issue now in the json but yaml is working great..

Comment: @AbhishekRatnam the top comment still holds as far as `encoding/json` is concerned, i.e. `omitempty` has no effect on emtpy structs and the package does not honor the "IsZeroer" interface. You'll have to use pointers.

Answer (score 2):

As documentation of yaml library in Go described, empty structs should be omitted with `omitempty` label.
Link - [pkg.go.dev/gopkg.in/yaml.v3](https://pkg.go.dev/gopkg.in/yaml.v3)

> omitempty
>
> ```
>          Only include the field if it's not set to the zero
>          value for the type or to empty slices or maps.
>          Zero valued structs will be omitted if all their public
>          fields are zero, unless they implement an IsZero
>          method (see the IsZeroer interface type), in which
>          case the field will be excluded if IsZero returns true.
> ```

Here is the sample prove code for that.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "gopkg.in/yaml.v3"
    "log"
)

type A struct {
    A int `yaml:"a"`
}

type B struct {
    B int `yaml:"b"`
    A A `yaml:"a,omitempty"`
}

func main() {
    b := B{
        B:5,
    }
    encoded, err := yaml.Marshal(b)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(`encoded - `,string(encoded)) //encoded -  b: 5
}
```

you can run code [here](https://play.golang.org/p/zAF0QmIIzTx)

Comment: Hi @nipuna for json would it also be the same, since i'm getting this issue now in the json but yaml is working great..

Comment: For json, you need to use pointers and pass empty struct as nil. see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18088294/how-to-not-marshal-an-empty-struct-into-json-with-go)